# iTunes connect cannot create new ios app version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit new version built to app store. Previously I got a submission and set it to manual release. The review is successful. But I chose to cancel the release. But now I am trying to submit new version but there is no option for iOS (as shown in picture).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rejected 1.0. You can't create a new version. Just submit an updated build for 1.0 and release that.

Comment: Can I submit new build 1.0.1?

Comment: No. Not until you release 1.0. No user has seen 1.0 yet. There's no reason to post 1.0.1. Just submit the binary you want to use. But it will appear to the user as 1.0.

Comment: in addition to attaching the new binary to the rejected release, you can also rename the release to 1.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

You must upload a new binary.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one version open.

You could, however, change the build (remove the old one first) and change the version number in the General App Information section.